# Move cursor to "next" TextBox after n chars

Tags: .net, wpf, textbox

I am writing a .NET (4.0) app where user will be entering e.g. 2 digits in a number of `TextBox`es and I would like the cursor to automatically advance to the "next" TextBox after the second character is entered in one. What is the best way to implement this?

EDIT: I have this`PreviewKeyDown` handler:

```
private void ODTextBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (allowedKeys.Contains(e.Key))
    {
        KeyConverter kc = new KeyConverter();
        string letter = kc.ConvertToString(e.Key);
        TextBox tb = (TextBox)sender;

        if (tb.Text.Length > 1 && tb.SelectedText.Length == 0)
        {
            this.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
        }
    }
}
```

However, the `MoveFocus` method always causes the focus to be moved to the first of my 10 TextBoxes.  I have `TabIndex` and `KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex` set for every `TextBox`, but that does not help.

Comment: [Have you Tried anything?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: @HighCore I've looked into capturing `KeyDown` events and programmatically generating keypresses to e.g. "tab" to the next field, but wondered if there was any "better" way.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void TextBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   if (...) //Your logic here   
      this.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
}
```

Comment: After some trial and error, `MoveFocus` needs to be called on `(TextBox)e.Source`, not `this` for the navigation to work properly.

Comment: While the next character typed will be in the "next" TextBox, the caret however does not move until the next button press.  Still looking for how to get the caret over as well.

Comment: Also: `MoveFocus` needs to be called in the `TextChanged` handler in order for the caret to be displayed in the next `TextBox`.